# Remove programs from automatic startup

Tags: xfce, startup, manjaro

When I start and log into my computer, multiple programs open on startup (mousepad, a terminal and firefox). How can I change this behaviour? I have no idea why it happens.

I am running Manjaro XFCE. I already tried using the graphical option menu, which does not list the programs mentioned above in the current startup applications.

Comment: You can look in ~/.xsessionrc file.

Comment: For some reason, this file does not seem to exist on my system.

Comment: There is a lot of possibility to open programs at startup. ~/.xsessionrc is one, autostart is another. On my debian, /etc/X11/Xsession.d/ is another one. I don't use Manjaro so I can't tell you. You can try to ask on Manjaro forum or [here](https://forum.xfce.org/index.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice from ctac_, i checked multiple possibilities to open applications at startup, but did not find anything that caused my problem. On the [Arch forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162764) someone had a similar problem, albeit while running Arch.

Their solution was to clear a faulty saved session by enabling the option "Automatically save session on logout" in the "Sessions and Startup" options, closing all applications and restarting XFCE. Afterwards, the enabled option may be disabled again.

This approach has worked for me as well :)

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the cache folder in your home folder. You'll want to uncheck 'Automatically save session on logout' under 'Sessions and Startup' as well.

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/
```